# Render output does not match with Viewport display

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Trying to render this scene. My render output looks different from how it appears in the viewport.
The ocean looks different in the attached two images, one of rendered output & one viewport screenshot. trying to render in cycles. Applied Ocean modifier to create the ocean.

Please guide me with your valuable feedback & comments. Also appreciate if any suggestions to make the scene look better or any scope of improvement elswhere

[image]
[image]

Comment: You render what camera sees and now what's on the viewport. Move your camera. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/camera_view.html

Comment: THe ocean modifier has a different setting for viewport and render subidivisions, make sure they're set to the same value

Comment: Hi :). Also, you're destroying A LOT of fine details using a denoiser on such a low sample count

Comment: Lastly, you have an object called "Floating Plane" that is hidden in your viewport (I'm guessing the blue/white thing). Objects hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders. If you want to keep it, but not have it visible, either disable its render visibility in Object Properties, or move it to a separate collection then Disable (_not Hide_) the collection.

Comment: Those were helpful tips, Gorgious, yes Ocean modifier has different settings for viewport & render subdivisions thanks for that. Christopher, the object "Floating plane" also disabled in the render, thank you. Jachym, I will take note of denoiser & play with those settings. Also, I need to mention one thing, I had two Oceans with different settings & both visible in render, that was one reason for my undesired render output result. Thank you all for your support.